# Visual Studio 2010 Web Load Testing - Requests Current does not go beyond 10 even the user load is more than 10

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, load-testing

I am writing some load test in Visual Studio for a sample ASP.NET web application. I create the web test and used that in a load test with a user load of 25. When I run the load test, I could see the Requests Current is 10. When I changed the user load to 2, now the Requests Current is 2. So it seems even when the user load is above 10, somehow the requests are serialized and only max of 10 requests are hiting the web server concurrently. Does it have any relation to the max number of requests per domain limit?

Comment: Need more details of your test. Have you tried a step load pattern? Try starting at 1 user, increment by 1 user every 10 seconds to a maximum 25, set the run duration to long enough that all tests can complete.

Comment: @AdrianHHH, I am using constant load pattern.

Comment: And the test behaviour with that constant load pattern is confusing you. So I suggested running a step load pattern that includes both constant loads you have described to see how the test works. Have you tried the pattern I suggested yet? What does it show?

Comment: @AdrianHHH, Now I got what is the reason for this. I am using Windows 7  on the Web Server. All Windows client operating systems have a maximum of 10 concurrent requests.